# oracle query to find the max data from every count values group by type

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have problem with query to find max in every count data and group by type

its my data

```
type|category|ratio|
1001    1       10
1001    1       10
1001    1        8
1001    1        6
1002    2        5
1002    2        5
1002    2        15
1003    3        2
```

and i have query to count all data like this

```
select type, category, ratio, count(ratio) from age_ratio group by type, category, ratio
```

and then the result is

```
type|category|ratio|count
1001    1       10   2
1001    1        8   1
1001    1        6   1
1002    2        5   2
1002    2        15  1
1003    3        2   1
```

and then i want to show data just have max(count) group by type, category, and ratio like this:

```
type|category|ratio|count
1001    1       10   2
1002    2        5   2
1003    3        2   1
```

my assumption query like this:

```
select r.type, r.category, r.ratio, 
max(r.num) as jum
from (select type, category, ratio, count(ratio) as num from age_ratio 
group by type, cat, ratio) r inner join ratio_age ra on
ra.type=r.type and ra.category=r.category and r.ratio=ra.ratio
group by r.type, r.category, r.ratio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select type, category, ratio, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from age_ratio
      group by type, category, ratio
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```